# How to add help files to an MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to add help to the different pages in my MVC3 application.  What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Each view could put some help info or help link in a section of your layout.
For instance, in your main layout you could have a "SideBarHelp" section... and use @RenderSection  to display what the view provides as help.

In the views you use:

```
@section SideBarHelp{
    //Your Help text or link here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion Romias.  I am however going to use jquery with dialogs to do this.

Comment: If you use jQuery, please post your solution... it is always a good to see alternatives!

Comment: Sure Romias. Once I've got it tested I will post it here.  Thank you for your help